# Nginx & php-fpm - host unreachable

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have docker swarm containing one nginx and one php-fpm service. My problem is, that from other services in swarm, I randomly get error `Failed to connect to nginx-fpm port 8081: Host unreachable`.

nginx and fpm images are from official docker images with little config changes.

nginx-fpm dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine

COPY ./nginx/config/ /etc/nginx/
ADD ./nginx/docker/entrypoint.sh /bin/

EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx config

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    accept_mutex on;
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 8081;
        server_name worker;

        keepalive_timeout 30;
        send_timeout 30s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 30s;
        client_max_body_size 1024M;

        root /app/www;
        index index.php;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried event enabling nginx_status, but I can only see 1 active connection (or host unreachable).

It looks like to me, that nginx is only able to handle one connection at time, but I cannot find reason why... any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your service in Swarm?

Generally, you need to expose the service port externally, something like this:

```
$ docker service create --name my_service \
                        --replicas 3 \
                        --publish published=8081,target=8081 \
                        nginx-fpm
```

Comment: It's only exposed via `EXPOSE`. I dont need to connect to this from outside, but only from other service in swarm. About half time I get response immediately, other times host unreachable...

Comment: it's your swarm running on a single machine?

Comment: It is on 2 servers

Comment: That's why you need to publish so that is not listening on `8081` can make requests to the one listening on `8081`. The server listening on `8081` can make requests locally on the same container network namespace.

Comment: If that would be the case, I wouldn't be able to connect at all, right? I can connect from same container, regardles on which server it is, but sometimes I get reponse, sometimes I get host unreachable...

Comment: that's why you see the error because it can connect half of the time